# Image from UIImagePickerController to UIImage image=

Tags: ios, uiimageview, imageview, uiimagepickercontroller

**Trying to load a camera/album photo into a 'add border' loop, but can't get it to work.**

The app basically takes a photo or picks one from album, then allows the user to choose between 4 different borders but as the user switches borders it doesn't revert back to the original photo it just layers the borders on top.

I've tried using

```
UIImage *image = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

But it doesn't like 'info'

Code below.

```
//  ABViewController.m

#import "ABViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
@interface ABViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *border1;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *border2;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *border3;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *border4;

@end

@implementation ABViewController

@synthesize imageView;

@synthesize border1, border2, border3, border4;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    border1.tag =1;
    border2.tag =2;
    border3.tag =3;
    border4.tag =4;
   imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"a7qIB4OiXsz5Q0BG4ipZV0FLF5_jB71p24h7Oa2ExYU.jpg"];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//Border code

- (IBAction)borderButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {



    UIImage* image=(UIImage*)[@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    UIImage *borderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"borderImage%i.png", sender.tag]];

    NSData *dataFromImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1);

    CIImage *beginImage= [CIImage imageWithData:dataFromImage];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *border =[CIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(borderImage)];

    CIFilter *filter= [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISourceOverCompositing"];  //@"CISoftLightBlendMode"];
    [filter setDefaults];
    [filter setValue:border forKey:@"inputImage"];

    [filter setValue:beginImage forKey:@"inputBackgroundImage"];

    CIImage *outputImage = [filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:[outputImage extent]];
    UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

    imageView.image = newImg;



}

// Camera CODE


- (IBAction)TakePhoto {
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [picker setShowsCameraControls:YES];
    [picker setAllowsEditing:YES];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [picker release];
}

- (IBAction)ChooseExisting {
    picker2 = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker2.delegate = self;
    [picker2 setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [picker2 setAllowsEditing:YES];
    [self presentViewController:picker2 animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [picker2 release];
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following...

Create a `NSDictionary` reference to hold onto the `info`:

```
@implementation ABViewController{
    NSDictionary *imageInfo;
}
```

In the `imagePickerController: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method add:

```
imageInfo = info;
```

In the `borderButtonTapped` method, replace:

```
UIImage* image=(UIImage*)[@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
```

with:

```
UIImage *image = [imageInfo valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
```

**Edit:**

and change:

```
NSData *dataFromImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 1);
```

to:

```
NSData *dataFromImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1);
```

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for the answer. I've done as you suggest but it's still saying Use of undeclared identifier 'info' next to the UIImage *iamge =...

Comment: I fixed the last line in the answer (was `info`, now `imageInfo`).

Comment: Hi Bob, it's now saying Unused variable 'image'. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: @PhilK - edited again so `dataFromImage` contains the original image data rather than the image from the `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thanks, It's breaking at the UIImage *image point with Thread 1: breakpoint 3.1. It's also saying local declration of 'image' hides instance varialble. Thanks, really appreciate your help.

Comment: @PhilK - where else is `image` being declared?